# as3 - Two defined movieclips in Array alpha/visible

Tags: actionscript-3

So I have two movieclips M1, and M2. I put then into an array and I need them to be randomly selected, and the one that gets selected will become visible while the other stays invisible. Is the code below a possible method? Note *this doesn't actually work in testing.*

```
    public var lanes:Array = [m1, m2];  
    public var m1:MovieClip;
    public var m2:MovieClip;

    function randomFromArray(array:Array):Number  
    {  
        return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];  
    }  

    public function onBc(event:TimerEvent):void  
    { 
        if (m1.alpha == 0 && m2.alpha == 0)
        {
        randomFromArray(lanes).alpha = 100;
        bc.stop();
        }

    }
```

Comment: There are 2 mistakes. First, it is possible that **m1** and **m2** are not transparent so the condition never works. Second, it must be **randomFromArray(lanes).alpha = 1;**, single = (assignment), not double == (comparison), also **alpha** is 0 to 1.

Comment: @Organis Hi That was not the problem. I did fix it up there to clear up confusion, but I am able to make movieclips go to 0 alpha by "m1.alpha = 0" but I am unable to make them go back to 100 through the array method.

Comment: I don't see any problems with your **getRandomArrayElement(...)** method. You need to **debug** your code. Put **trace(...)** before every line to check if all the variables carry the values you expect, and not something else. The detailed description about how to debug small AS3 applications you can read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47855213/4687633

Comment: Like Organis mentioned the alpha goes from 0 to 1, not from 0 to 100. So it can have values 0.3, 0.7 etc and 1 for 100% - maybe that is the problem? Just on a side note it is always better to set the .visible property to true or false rather than manipulate the alpha. visible=false also removes the movieclips from the display list which is better performance wise. Besides of that the buttons will stay clickable if you just set the alpha to 0.

Comment: @Philarmon I see, I changed to try to 1 or 0.5 and it gave me this error " Warning: 1072: Migration issue: Number is not a dynamic class. Instances cannot have members added to them dynamically." Also note, I did switch to visible property thank you for advice. But the error is stil same.