# Collision not being detected actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3

"package  {

```
public class CollisionComponent {

    var possessed;
    var platformArray:Array;

    public function CollisionComponent(pEntityArray : Array) {

        possessed = pEntityArray[0];
        platformArray = pEntityArray;
    }

    public function CollisionTest()
    {



        if(possessed.x > platformArray[1].x - platformArray[1].width / 2 && 
            possessed.x < platformArray[1].x + platformArray[1].width / 2 &&
        possessed.y - possessed.height / 2 > platformArray[1].y)
        {
            possessed.gravityOn = false;
            trace("it works");
        }
    }

    public function Update()
    {
        CollisionTest();
    }

}
```

}"

I am trying to get collision to detect between the platforms on my game and the player token we have created. I put in a trace to make sure it was reaching the if statement and that seems to be working. However on actual testing of the game no collision appears to be working.

Any suggestions on what might be stopping it from working would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If this code is working while testing but not working once you implement it, then the problem is **not with this code**. It could be your display list hierarchy, or you pass wrong initial data, or something else.

Comment: The only other interference I would think of would be related to the keyboard input I have implemented. But I personally can't see a correlation between the two.

Comment: It can not work if objects are in different coordinate spaces. Anyway, it's time for you to learn the **trace(...)** command. If the logic is correct (I don't see the problem with logic) then it's the data to blame. You need to trace all the data to understand how exactly they go wrong and why. Also you might want to read how to debug AS3 apps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47855213/4687633