# Controlling frame navigation inside a sourced MC from inside another MC

Tags: actionscript-3

In my swf, I have a MC (let's call it MC1) as well as a scrollpane which is connected to a different MC in the library (let's call that one MC2).

Part of what I'm trying to do is make it so that when an element inside MC1 is dragged and dropped, it makes MC2 go to frame #2, and also makes MC2 scroll up to a certain position.

So far I'm just trying to get the frame navigation to work. Here is the code below. "squareDrag" is the instance name for the element in MC1 I'm going to drag and drop. "mcPane1" is the instance name for the scrollpane on the main timeline. I don't have an instance name for MC2 since it's not on the stage, only in the library. I read something about using "source" instead of an instance name when referring to something inside a scrollpane, so I tried that first.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging, true);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging, true);

function startDragging(e:MouseEvent) {
squareDrag.startDrag();
}

function stopDragging(e:MouseEvent) {
squareDrag.stopDrag();
MovieClip(root).(mcPane1.source).gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

What is it I should be doing here? I'm assuming it's something simple I just haven't been able to find through google.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably **MovieClip(root).mcPane1.source.gotoAndStop(2);** without that extra parentheses. Dot notation works as following: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#dot

Comment: Organis - I put that line of code into my flash file, and got the following error:  TypeError: Error #1006: gotoAndStop is not a function.

Comment: Well, that means **mcPane1.source** is not a **MovieClip**. You need to **trace(...)** everything to learn the complete picture you are dealing with. Read about trace-debugging AS3 here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47855213/4687633

Comment: Thanks Organis...The source for the scrollpane in the library is a movie clip called mc2.  the code i used to link the movie clip to the scrollpane is: mcPane1.source = mc2; --the "mc2" was the class name that flash assigned the movie clip under ActionScript Linkage in the Properties panel for that library item.  I'm not exactly an expert in AS3, so I'm used to using instance names in the coding, but the linked library item for the scrollpane component doesn't have an instance name...I assumed that ".source" was actionscript's way of saying "go into the library source for this scrollpane"?

Comment: You may also try **mcPane1.source = new mc2;** It is possible that **mcPane1.source** will keep the direct reference to the pane content.

Comment: That worked!! Thank you...